# Squish svg vertically after window height is smaller than the container

Tags: html, css, svg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Astloch' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        svg {
            display: block;
            border: 5px solid black;
            position: absolute;
            top: 5%;
            left: 5%;
            width: 90%;
            height: 90%;
            background: #fff;
        }

        .face {
            stroke: #000;
            stroke-width: 20px;
            stroke-linecap: round
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item1">
            <div class="flex-container">
                <div class="align-middle">
                    <div>DUI/DWI</div>
                </div>
                <div class="align-middle">
                    <div>CASE RESULTS / BLOG</div>
                </div>
                <div class="align-middle">
                    <div>CONTACT US</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item2">Left</div>
        <div class="item3">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua. Sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. In vitae turpis
                massa sed elementum tempus egestas. Adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Dolor sit amet consectetur
                adipiscing elit ut aliquam. Quis viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Eu turpis egestas pretium
                aenean pharetra magna ac placerat. Mauris cursus mattis molestie a. Imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta
                lorem mollis aliquam ut porttitor. Fermentum iaculis eu non diam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
                senectus.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="item4">Right</div>
        <div class="item5">Footer</div>
    </div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-350 -250 700 500">
        <circle r="200" class="face" fill="red" />
        <path fill="none" class="face" transform="translate(-396,-230)"
            d="M487.41,282.411c-15.07,36.137-50.735,61.537-92.333,61.537         c-41.421,0-76.961-25.185-92.142-61.076" />
        <circle cx="-60" cy="-50" r="20" fill="#000" />
        <circle cx="60" cy="-50" r="20" fill="#000" />
    </svg>
    <script>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Currently it scales in both sides when the width or height is smaller than it should be. I want to keep the scaling behavior in small widths but want it to squish on one side instead of scale from two in small heights. If you have any questions just message from here please.

Answer (score 0):

Add the property `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice"` in ur svg.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-350 -250 700 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice">
```

Comment: This squishes in both directions, I only want it to squish in one direction.

Comment: @user3507230 my bad, try `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid slice"`